# Entity Framework Core deletes entities during update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a problem concerning entities in ASP.NET Core.
I use Entity Framework Core as data access library.
The issue I've come across happens when I'm trying to update an entity. After I modify the properties and call SaveChanges, the entity gets deleted and I don't understand why.
Here's the entity:

```
public class Contract
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Range(0, float.MaxValue)]
        public float MonthlyFee { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CarId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public Car Car { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's the related entities for reference:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        [PersonalData]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [PersonalData]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [PersonalData]
        public string TaxCode { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [PersonalData]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePictureUrl { get; set; }
        
        public Contract Contract { get; set; }

        public ICollection<CarAccident> CarAccidents { get; set; }
    }
public class Car
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression("[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z][A-Z]")]
        public string LicensePlate { get; set; }
        public int CarModelId { get; set; }
        public string FittingDescription { get; set; }
        public Contract Contract { get; set; }

        public ICollection<CarAccident> CarAccidents { get; set; }

        public CarModel CarModel { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's my update method in repository:

```
public async Task<Contract> Update(Contract entity)
        {
            var dbContract = await GetById(entity.Id);
            if (dbContract == null)
                return null;

            var dbUser = await _userRepository.GetById(entity.UserId);
            if (dbUser == null)
                return null;

            var dbCar = await _carRepository.GetById(entity.CarId);
            if (dbCar == null)
                return null;

            dbContract.ExpiryDate = entity.ExpiryDate;
            dbContract.User = entity.User;
            dbContract.Car = dbCar;
            dbContract.User = dbUser;

            //_context.Contracts.FromSqlInterpolated($"UPDATE dbo.Contracts SET ExpiryDate={entity.ExpiryDate}, MonthlyFee={entity.MonthlyFee} WHERE Id={entity.Id}");

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return await GetById(entity.Id);
        }
```

Has anyone got any idea how to solve this?

## UPDATE:

This is the new Update method:

```
public async Task<Contract> Update(Contract entity)
        {
            var dbContract = await GetById(entity.Id);
            if (dbContract == null)
                return null;

            var dbUser = await _userRepository.GetById(entity.UserId);
            if (dbUser == null)
                return null;

            var dbCar = await _carRepository.GetById(entity.CarId);
            if (dbCar == null)
                return null;

            dbContract.ExpiryDate = entity.ExpiryDate;
            dbContract.Car = dbCar;
            dbContract.User = dbUser;

            //_context.Contracts.FromSqlInterpolated($"UPDATE dbo.Contracts SET ExpiryDate={entity.ExpiryDate}, MonthlyFee={entity.MonthlyFee} WHERE Id={entity.Id}");

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return await GetById(entity.Id);
        }
```

Here's the Fluent API configuration:

```
private void _configureUsers(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasOne(u => u.Contract)
                .WithOne(c => c.User)
                .HasForeignKey<Contract>(c => c.UserId);
        }
private void _configureCars(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
                .HasAlternateKey(c => c.LicensePlate);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Car>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Contract)
                .WithOne(c => c.Car)
                .HasForeignKey<Contract>(c => c.CarId);
        }
```

Both this methods get called in the OnModelCreating method of the context.

Comment: You put twice dbContract.User delete one.

Comment: You are updating `dbContract.User` twice, that's not good anyway even if it is not source of your problem. Move `dbContract.User = entity.User; dbContract.Car = dbCar;dbContract.User = dbUser;` after `SaveChanges` and delete one of user updates.

Comment: Also you are not updating `MonthlyFee={entity.MonthlyFee}` from your `FromSqlInterpolated` query.

Comment: There seems to be some "one-to-one" mappings (`User.Contract <-> Contract.User` and `Car.Contract <-> Contract.Car`) which might be causing the issue. Can you post the relevant fluent configuration?

Comment: @GuruStron I did as you had suggested but unfortunately is not solving my issue

Comment: when you say it deletes it, but it also adds the new one right..? that would be by design, you would need to change your relationship to  allow "one to many"..//

Comment: @IvanStoev I've updated the post with the fluent api configuration

Comment: No @Seabizkit, the old one gets deleted but the new one is not added. Both the relationships `contract <-> user` and `contract <-> car` should be one to one.

Comment: my guess is user.. which you are assigning already has a contract?, try set the id. rather than the nav properties and see if it improves things.`dbContract.UserId= dbUser.UserId;` and get rid of the nav assignments for now.

Comment: also it not normal to fetch the entities in an assignment like you are doing.... if the entity has the values then there is no need to fetch. if its 0 then you know its new.

Comment: @DanyNass based on your update code - you have not tried everything i suggested. Try moving `dbContract.Car = dbCar; dbContract.User = dbUser;` after the `SaveChanges` statement.

Comment: Also I would say that you should not invoke other repository methods and just fetch everything directly: `var dbContract = _context.Contracts.Include(c =>c.Car).Include(c =>c.User).Where(c => c.Id == entity.Id)`

Comment: @GuruStron I've tried to move the `dbContract.Car = dbCar` and `dbContract.User = dbUser` after SaveChanges but it doesn't work. Thank you for all your suggestions by the way.

Comment: @DanyNass NP. Is `Update` the only method working with db which is called in your code in this hierarchy of methods for this situation to happen?

Comment: @DanyNass Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please provide `GetById` method(s) and the EF Core version.

Comment: I've finally managed to solve it, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally managed to solve my issue.
I was already tracking the entity in my api controller like that:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Backoffice")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ContractDTO>> PutContract(int id, [FromBody] PutContractViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (viewModel == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(new { message = "Your model is wrong" });


            var contract = await _contractService.GetContractDTO(id);

            if (contract == null)
                return NotFound();

            var modifiedContract = await _contractService.UpdateContract(viewModel);

            if (modifiedContract == null)
                return BadRequest(new { message = "User or car may be busy in another contract" });

            return Ok(modifiedContract);
        }
```

This type of approach works in one to many relationships, but evidently when you have one to one relationship and you have to objects that rapresent the same entity the ChangeTracker cannot track the changes correctly.
I post my new controller and repository code if someone will burst into my same problem.
Controller:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Backoffice")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ContractDTO>> PutContract(int id, [FromBody] PutContractViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (viewModel == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(new { message = "Your model is wrong" });


            ContractDTO modifiedContract;
            try
            {
                modifiedContract = await _contractService.UpdateContract(viewModel);
            }
            catch (EntityNotFoundException)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }


            if (modifiedContract == null)
                return BadRequest(new { message = "User or car may be busy in another contract" });

            return Ok(modifiedContract);
```

Service:

```
public async Task<ContractDTO> UpdateContract(PutContractViewModel viewModel)
        {
            try
            {
                return await ParseContractToContractDTO(await _contractRepository.Update(ParsePutContractViewModelToContract(viewModel)));
            }
            catch(EntityNotFoundException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Repository:

```
public async Task<Contract> Update(Contract entity)
        {

            var dbContract = await _context.Contracts.Include(c => c.User).Include(c => c.Car).FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == entity.Id);

            if (dbContract == null)
            {
                throw new EntityNotFoundException();
            }

            var dbUser = await _context.Users.Include(u => u.Contract).FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == entity.UserId);

            if (dbUser == null)
                return null;

            var dbCar = await _context.Cars.Include(c => c.Contract).FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == entity.CarId);

            if (dbCar == null)
                return null;


            dbContract.ExpiryDate = entity.ExpiryDate;
            dbContract.MonthlyFee = entity.MonthlyFee;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                return null;
            }



            return await GetById(entity.Id);
        }
```

I want to thank you all, you've been very helpful and patient with me.

Comment: that seem even more fishy!!!!, show the code for _contractService, where/how is _contractService instantiated. your code does not seems to be following good practices. also add code for ParsePutContractViewModelToContract(viewModel)

Comment: in ur first version where u did `var contract = await _contractService.GetContractDTO(id);` this entity is now being tracked so you could of simply updated this entity and called save-changes...